# Basic authentication vs GET parameters

Tags: security, get, basic-authentication

I would like to create a secret page protected by a password.
To access the secret page, the user shouldn't have to manually input anything. Instead, there should be a secret link that contains the password which would lead directly to the secret page. We assume that this secret link is shared exclusively among trusted parties.

I thought of two options:

- https://user:secretpassword@www.example.com/secret
- https://www.example.com/secret?user=user&password=secretpassword

Requests being made exclusively over HTTPs, is one more secure than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are really both equally insecure, even if communicated over https.

The problem is that you can't keep your users from being able to see the username and password in the link. And if users can see it, there's really no way to keep it safe.

Also, depending on the web server configuration, these usernames and passwords could end up in server logs etc.

The only way to make sure the HTTP request is coming from your web application, is to authenticate the users and protect the page with appropriate access controls.